# Social media and regular login in app using own db

Tags: android, ios, authentication, social-media

I'm currently building an app (android and ios) for which I now need users to be able to login. It must be possible to both sign up regularly (entering username, password, name, mail etc.) and to login through various not yet determined social media such as facebook, twitter, gmail, hotmail.

Now my questions are as follows:
 1. Are there any framework's supporting this kind of in-app+social media login scenario ? (I know there is stuff like auth0 but it seems that you don't have that much control with this. As I'm going to save statistics about user navigation and such I think it would be preferable to store all my users in my own db, regardless of their way of logging in. Thus to me it seems like what I need is just an easy way of getting information from these social media and then register users as if they had just signed up regularly am I right ? 
 2. Anything obvious I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these social media sites have their own sdk's that allow you to login users and get certain information from them. So using a website like facebook's sdk you request certain information about the user logging in such as email and first/last name, then save this information in your database including it came from facebook. You will need to also create/encrypt a password for someone coming from a site like this. This is very important, obviously they won't give you access to a user's password but you don't want the user's account on your website to be vulnerable. I would limit the number of ways to login because you will have to program and work with each websites sdk in order to do this. Probably just use your own login and a facebook login to start

Here is a link to facebooks website for developers which gives you access to their sdk's for different platforms `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks`

Comment: Cool James, thanks. I figured this might be the way to do it. I was hoping there was some framework that might "encapsulate" these social media frameworks in one so I did not have to implement each one of them by myself. You know if such a thing exists ?

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/ may be able to for android/java apps, don't know about iOS. I haven't heard or seen anyone, but I feel like your login screen would be crowded if you had too many different types of login. The main one's generally are native login, facebook, and google+ I would say

Comment: Great, good to know I'm on the right track! What about my own login screen. Any frameworks for that or should I just implement it from scratch ?